# Setting SRC of an image using Wordpress get_option

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image, src

I am trying to use the get_option() function in Wordpress to set the SRC of an image in a theme file. The file is index.php, and represents the homepage.

The current image code is:

`<img class="outside-collage-image" <?php echo 'src="'.get_option('article-image-1').'"'; ?>>`

However, the image doesn't display, and when I inspect it, it simply says `src(unknown)` where it should have the proper SRC

I have tried a myriad of fixes, including leaving the SRC out of the php area and simply calling the function, but it doesn't seem to work.

The oddest part is, if I put on the page `<p><?php echo 'src="'.get_option('article-image-1').'"'; ?></p>` to check the output, it outputs into the `<p>` the proper code: `src="http://image-site.com/my-image.jpg"` (obviously the link to the image is fake, but the point is, it's a valid link.)

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Try with this code `<img class="outside-collage-image" src="<?php echo esc_url(get_option('article-image-1')); ?>"' >`

Comment: @htmlbrewery The problem is, I don't want to escape HTML- I want it to output as an actual HTML link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the image article-image-1.jpg in your root.

```
 <img class="outside-collage-image" src="<?php echo get_site_url().'/article-image-1.jpg'; ?>">
```

Comment: The problem is, the SRC needs to be able to be set manually and changed at any point via an external setting.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I screwed up, and the above function works just fine. I was simply applying it to the wrong image, and didn't realize that until looking at it a day later, when it wasn't 1:30 AM and I wasn't so tired. Thanks to all that answered.

*headdesk*